# PHPUnit - Check if an array contains an object of a specific type

Tags: php, arrays, unit-testing, phpunit

While unit testing in PHPUnit, I'm in a situation where I need to check if an array contains al least one object of a specific type.

Here's a trivial example of what I'm looking for

```
$obj_1 = new Type1;
$obj_2 = new Type2; 

$container = array( $obj_1, $obj_2 );

// some logic and array manipulation here

// need something like this
$this->assertArrayHasObjectOfClass( 'Type1', $container );
```

Obviously I can do that with custom code, but is there any assertion (or combination of them) which allows me to do that?

I need to do that many times in multiple tests so, if the assertion I need doesn't esist, how do I extend the set of PHPUnit assertions?

**EDIT: custom solution with trait**

As suggested by Vail, I came up with a custom solution for this using traits. Here's a semplified version.

```
// trait code
trait CustomAssertTrait
{
    public function assertArrayHasObjectOfType( $type, $array, $message = '' ) {

        $found = false;

        foreach( $array as $obj ) {
            if( get_class( $obj ) === $type ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        $this->assertTrue( $found, $message );

    }
}

// test code
class CustomTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   use CustomAssertTrait;

   // test methods... 
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a minimal working example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: If found you probably want to `break` out of the loop.

Comment: You can try [assertInstanceOf()](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/Assert.php#L1236) as the [example](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/tests/Framework/AssertTest.php#L3835).

Comment: I don't think I can because I have to put it in a for/foreach loop and if the first occurrence is not the class I'm looking for, then the execution will stop.

Answer (score 5):

If you check only one object use method assertContains() and place array or Traversable as second parameter. But here object must have same properties as one you are looking for (eg. id, title, etc.)
ex.

```
$obj_x = new Type1;
$this->assertContains($obj_x, $container);
```

If all objects in array or Traversable have same ancestor or interface, you can use method assertContainsOnlyInstancesOf() ex.

```
$this->assertContainsOnlyInstancesOf(Type1Type2Interface::class, $container);
```

https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContainsOnlyInstancesOf

Answer (score 1):

Answering since I was looking for an info too and found that while digging in methods list:

- phpunit-version: `9.5.13`
- method name: `assertContainsOnly`
- example: `$this->assertContainsOnly(Dto::class, $this->provider->provide());`

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think that there is an assertion for this. You will need to write some custom code.

About extendig PHPUnit assertions you could create trait with your own assertion method and add it to specific tests.

Or look at this https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your solution:

```
$found = (bool)array_filter($array, function($v) use ($type) {
                                        return get_class($v) === $type;
                                    });
```

Comment: This is a smart solution to have everything in one line. But I think that my solution with your suggestion (I added a break in foreach loop) it's a bit memory safer. Moreover, I don't know how PHP closures are implemented on low level in case of array_filter. I mean, is the closure created everytime it loops or is it created once and then used by all the iterations?

Comment: Created once. array_filter is small wrapper around efficient C code. It's faster or as fast as any php loop without early exit.

Comment: the array is the first arg and not the callback